# How to convert java swing panel to quality image

Tags: java, swing, pdf, export, bufferedimage

my panel looks like:

[image]

when I convert to image

```
public BufferedImage createImage(JPanel panel) {

int w = (int) PageSize.A4.getWidth();//panel.getWidth();
int h = (int) PageSize.A4.getHeight();//panel.getHeight();

BufferedImage originalImage = new BufferedImage(panel.getHeight(), panel.getWidth(), BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_INDEXED);
Graphics2D gg = originalImage.createGraphics();
gg.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION,
        RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BILINEAR);
gg.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING,
        RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY);
gg.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
        RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
panel.paint(gg);

BufferedImage resizedImage = new BufferedImage(w, h, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
Graphics2D g = resizedImage.createGraphics();
g.drawImage(originalImage, 0, 0, w, h, null);
g.dispose();
g.setComposite(AlphaComposite.Src);

g.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION,
        RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BILINEAR);
g.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING,
        RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY);
g.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
        RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

return resizedImage;
}
```

it looks terrible - larger and worse quality

[image]

how I can change quaity of this image to the quality of panel ?

EDIT:

library which you need to compile this code:

```
import com.itextpdf.text.PageSize;
import java.awt.AlphaComposite;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
```

Comment: I guess you just ignored my suggestion in your other thread. Your choice. Best of luck.

Comment: what do you mean ? I just inspired with it when I am changing size of this image

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).
Not that I haven't commented that before, to you.

Comment: and can you be more specific what with ssccce is not in this example ? It is short I explain the problem and this code is compilable

Comment: Try posting that code in your IDE and see whether it compiles and can be run. Or even better, just dump it in an empty file and try using the command line to compile it ... this code simply does not compile. And concerning your question ... of course it looks larger as you upscale it to A4 instead of using the size of your panel. What did expect was going to happen ?

Comment: when I copy this code to the my IDE it is compilated. Maybe you havnt got right library:

Comment: The code doesn't have a class, lacks imports, ... . It simply isn't valid Java syntax. Further it lacks a main method allowing us to run the code and reproduce your issue.You might have copy-pasted this code from your IDE, but it is only a part of the full Java file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To literally answer your question:

*how I can change quality of this image to the quality of panel ?*

Simple, do not alter the size of your image. Drop the whole 'stretching your image to A4 size' as this is the cause of the quality loss.

```
public BufferedImage createImage(JPanel panel) {
  BufferedImage originalImage = new BufferedImage(
        panel.getHeight(), panel.getWidth(), 
        BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_INDEXED);
  Graphics2D gg = originalImage.createGraphics();
  gg.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION,
        RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BILINEAR);
  gg.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING,
        RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY);
  gg.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
        RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
  panel.paint(gg);
  gg.dispose();
  return originalImage;
}
```

Not sure however if this is what you have been looking for. If you really want the image to be on A4 size, I suggest trying to get your panel sharply rendered on A4 size before converting it to an image. Stretching a small image to a larger version will always result in quality loss.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the Graphics2D transform so the panel's paint immediately goes to the scaled image

```
BufferedImage resizedImage = new BufferedImage(w, h, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
Graphics2D g = resizedImage.createGraphics();
g.transform(AffineTransform.getScaleInstance((float)panel.getWidth()/w,
          (float)panel.getHeight()/h));//this might need to be inverted I'm not sure...
panel.paint(g);
g.dispose();
```

btw the setRenderingHint won't do anything useful after you disposed the Graphics

Comment: hm thx but this just change size but quality is still very bad