# How to convert higher JPanel to the pdf

Tags: java, swing, pdf, export

height of my panel is 1600. Height of A4 format has height 842. How can I export this panel to the pdf with two pages ? Or how I can split this panel in half to the two graphics and then on add to first page then call `document.newPage();` and second graphics add to second page

Comment: This looks awfully similar to your previous thread(s) including: [How to convert java swing panel to quality image](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10366660/how-to-convert-java-swing-panel-to-quality-image)

Comment: nope, there I wanna export panel to the image. Now I want to export panel to the pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you plan to use iText, in a nutshell,

You need to implement a java.awt.print.Pageable, just as for normal Java printing.  In your example case, it will have 2 pages, which will be Printables.  Typically, in the Printable method

```
print(Graphics graphics, PageFormat pageFormat, int pageIndex)
```

you will translate the incoming graphics according to the page number.  e.g. translate by pageIndex*842 in your example.  There may be a minus sign there - in my experience you have a 50:50 chance to get the direction right.  :-)  There may also be margins to worry about.

Then, buy the book iText in Action (2nd edition) and look around page 485 for how to do general PDF creation from Swing.

Loop over each page.

```
for (int pageIndex=0; pageIndex< pageable.getNumberOfPages(); pageIndex++) {
   Graphics2D g2d = contentByte.createGraphics(width, height, fontMapper);
   Printable printable = pageable.getPrintable(pageIndex);
   PageFormat pageFormat = pageable.getPageFormat(pageIndex);
   int pageStatus = printable.print(g2d, pageFormat, pageIndex);
   if (pageStatus != Printable.PAGE_EXISTS)
      break;  // something screwey happenned
   g2d.dispose();
}
```

As you may have guessed, I've just been doing this, and may post a blog with more complete code in a couple of days.  So stay tuned.

Comment: hm nice example. bwt there is some other library for exporting which can do this better ?